# Content types for file upload

Tags: php, api, file-upload, content-type

I wanted to upload a file(any format) to an api. If I upload the file using multipart/form-data then the file gets uploaded.

I wanted to upload the file using application/json  as the Content-type  in the header. 
Could you'll tell me if this method is possible/allowed?

Which are Content-type besides multipart/form-data which supports file upload?

Is there a single standard for content type which can be used for get, put, post etc.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: We can't tell you what is possible without knowing the specifics of the API in question...

Comment: The api is not yet created.. but from development point of view. I wanted to know what content-types in header allow for file upload?

Answer (score 0):

Only `multipart/form-data` can trigger the population of the PHP `$_FILES` global, otherwise you're going to need to nest your attachment data in your API request if using something like JSON or XML  (base64_encoding comes to mind)

You could also process a PUT request - http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.put-method.php

Comment: Is there a single standard for content type which can be used for get, put, post etc?

Answer (score 0):

[RFC 4627:](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt)

```
The MIME media type for JSON text is application/json
```